# Using jQuery to toggle layer with opacity to darken rest of web page

Tags: jquery, css

I have a web page with 2 main area. The header which is 'fixed' and about 40px high, then the area below that which the rest of my site content falls into (site is not yet published so can't provide a link unfortunately). The same sort of layout as this though:

[www.wookmark.com](http://www.wookmark.com)

When I click on a certain image in the main content area, I want to apply a near black (but with opacity so you can still just see through it) layer, covering the whole website, but have the image I clicked on remain unchanged. An example of the exact sort of thing I'm trying to do is used on [500px.com](http://500px.com/photo/20487489).

If you click on the image, everything else blacks out around it (even when you scroll down the page).

I've tried to accomplish this by setting a background to the BODY element via jquery, but the only time I got it half working, for some reason, it was not applying it to the 'fixed' header - that remained white and unchanged whilst the rest of the page changed.

Any suggestions on how to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a div with an absolute position at the end of your body. And "clone" your image in this div.

Short example :

CSS :

```
.layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left : 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.layer img {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').click(function() {
   var layer = $('<div class="layer" />');
   $('body').append(layer);

   layer.append($(this).clone);
});
```

This is just a short example to show you the basics. You should re-use the same layer every time and of course you must give a way to hide the layer (by cliking on it for instance).

You may want to use a external technology to help you. Just take a look at Lightbox : http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/